# Primefaces Captcha disappears or doesn't update/refresh on invalid input?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, captcha

I have the following piece of code inside an `h:form`

```
<h:panelGrid id="captchaGrid">
    <p:captcha id="captcha" label="Captcha" required="true"
        requiredMessage="required"
        validatorMessage="...">
    </p:captcha>
    <p:message id="captchaMessage" for="captcha" />
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="save"
    actionListener="#{userBean.save}" update="captchaGrid"
    onstart="doSomething()"
    oncomplete="doSomethingElse(xhr, status, args)" icon="ui-icon-check">
</p:commandButton>
```

This works fine if I enter the captcha correctly. However, if I enter an invalid value, the captcha component just disappears.

I tried removing the `update="captchaGrid"` attribute. This time, the captcha didn't disappear. Instead, it didn't refresh visually but (I guess) internally. Because typing the two words correctly still generates a validation error.

Furthermore; I don't want to use `ajax="false"`.

**Update:** I also tried `oncomplete="Recaptcha.reload()"`. Didn't work. There is a bug. But I don't know if it's my code or Primefaces 3.0 :)

**Update 2:** As maple_shaft pointed out, it turns out that this is a problem with Primefaces/Recaptcha. So I'm looking for any dirty hacks you might suggest.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not going to like my answer, but this is not a bug.

[Primefaces Issue 1642](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1642) is marked as Won't Fix.

The Primefaces Captcha utilizes Recaptcha, which does not and cannot support Ajax refresh.  You must do a full page postback for this component to work properly.  Keep in mind this also affects the ability to use the Captcha in components that require Ajax refresh of a panel, such as a Tab View or Wizard component.

**EDIT:** On another note, it might be possible to use the captcha component within an `<iframe>` to achieve a similar effect, but that seems like a dirty hack.  Sorry I couldn't be more of a help.

Comment: I really didn't like your answer maple_shaft, but thanks :) Is there a way I can submit an `h:form` which contains an `iframe`? Ofcourse, I'd like to submit the contents of the `iframe` as well.

Comment: @Murat I don't believe that is how iframes work.  The content of the iframe is a completely different page so for that to be possible some clever Javascript is probably needed.  I haven't used iframes in over 8 years so I can't remember much.  You should ask about submitting a form within an iframe from the master page in a different question to get a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is dirty but try using captcha on on dialog. it is working for me....

```
  <p:dialog widgetVar="captchaDlgWar" modal="true" closable="false" resizable="false"
              header="Prove you are human..." width="350" height="200">

        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">

                <p:captcha label="Captcha"
                           id="captchaId"
                           language="tr"
                           theme="white"
                           required="true"
                           requiredMessage="Please Enter Capcha Text"
                           validatorMessage="Captcha text does not match."/>
                <p:commandButton id="btnContinue"
                                 ajax="false"
                                 value="Continue"
                                 actionListener="#{MyBean.onButtonAction}"/>

            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

MyBean------->

```
public void onButtonAction(ActionEvent e) {
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("captchaDlgWar.hide()");
   //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A derivation of the @user2393398 tip.

Do not update the `p:captcha`, use the `p:ajaxStatus` to reload it.

```
<h:form style="width: 400px;" >
    <h:outputText value="Informe seu CPF/CNPJ ou E-mail abaixo, e um e-mail de recuperação será enviado para seu endereço." />
    <br /><br />
    <p:messages id="messageGlobal" globalOnly="true" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="5" >
        <h:outputLabel for="inputUsuarioRecuperacao" value="CPF/CNPJ ou E-mail: " style="float: right;"/>    
        <p:inputText id="inputUsuarioRecuperacao" value="#{loginController.usuario}" required="true" size="30" />
        <p:message id="messageUsuarioRecuperacao" for="inputUsuarioRecuperacao" display="icon" />
        <p:spacer />
        <p:captcha id="inputCaptcha" theme="white" secure="true" validatorMessage="Os caracteres inseridos não correspondem à verificação de palavras. Tente novamente." />
        <p:message id="messageCaptcha" for="inputCaptcha" display="icon" />
        <p:spacer />
        <p:commandButton value="Enviar" actionListener="#{loginController.enviarEmailRecuperarSenha()}" update="messageGlobal messageCaptcha messageUsuarioRecuperacao" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:ajaxStatus onsuccess="Recaptcha.reload();" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Yeah just adding `<p:ajaxStatus oncomplete="Recaptcha.reload();" />` seems to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way of reloading the captcha, so what I do is to reload it in the event oncomplete or onerror using JavaScript.

```
Recaptcha.reload();
```

Maybe it'll work for you.