# Primefaces and selectors

Tags: primefaces

I have a `tabView` component and in each `tab` panel, I have a `form`.

I have also a flag image to change locale in my application and when it's clicked, I want to reload all `tabView` with new locale changes.

In one form in a `tab` panel, I use `captcha` component and I don't want to reload it because...it's impossible without all reload page (doesn't support partial Ajax reloading, I will use `Recaptcha.reload()` JS to do the job of reloading).

So I want to reload all my `tabView` component nested in `panel` component named...`panel` without my captcha.

- my `tabView` is nested in panel named `panel`
- my captcha has id `captcha`

My 2 locale change buttons are these one :

```
<p:commandLink update="@(:panel:not(captcha))" rendered="#{locale.locale != 'fr'}">
    <h:graphicImage url="resources/images/flags/flag_fr.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{locale.locale}" value="fr" />
</p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink update=":panel" rendered="#{locale.locale != 'en'}">
    <h:graphicImage url="resources/images/flags/flag_en.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{locale.locale}" value="en" />
</p:commandLink>
```

I have tested much combinaisons of selectors inside `update` attribute but without success.

Any selector idea please ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

When you are using PFS you are referencing client id of the componenets. For example if client id of your panel is `:panel`, your selector will be `@(#\\:panel)` (you have to escape semicolon). Inspect your generated html and find out real client ids of your components. If the component is in naming container id of container is concatenated before id of child compoenent. For example if panel is naming container of your captcha it would be something like: `@(#\\:panel:not(#\\:panel\\:captcha))`. Forms are also naming container so probably your ids will have something more near this.

Comment: Hi, thank you. My captcha id is translated to div container with id name `recaptcha_widget_div`. For now, I'm just testing to reload only this div to know which syntax I should use after to reload all without my captcha. `@(#recaptcha_widget_div)` or `@(#\\:recaptcha_widget_div)` don't work

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979089/primefaces-captcha-disappears-or-doesnt-update-refresh-on-invalid-input)

Comment: I already saw this post but it doesn't correspond to my need. In my case, I can refresh captcha with `Recaptcha.reload()` and it's work fine. I simply want to refresh all my `tabView` except my captcha (which will be updated via `Recaptcha.reload()` on the `oncomplete` event). I know I can select manually all the fields to refresh but I think it's possible to use selectors...so I search ^^ Thank you anyway