# PrimeFaces wizard with captcha

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, captcha, wizard

I am trying implement `<p:captcha>` into `<p:wizard>` PrimeFaces. I found only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979089/primefaces-captcha-disappears-or-doesnt-update-refresh-on-invalid-input/8986419#8986419) post with similar problem, when capcha in a wizard will disappear on invalid input. The proposed solution doesn't work for me.

**Main question:** is possible insert capcha into PrimeFaces wizard by some propper way?

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't come up with a proper solution (the AJAX update of wizard tabs prevents the iframe of the Recaptcha control to be reloaded) but I created a simple workaround:

1. position `<p:captcha>` outside of the `<p:wizard>`
2. position the captcha iframe absolutely, so it gets moved inside the wizard
3. hide it with CSS and
4. unhide the captcha inside the `flowListener` method on the appropriate wizard tab:

e.g.

```
public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {  

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if ("confirm".equals(event.getNewStep())) {
        context.execute("jQuery(document.getElementById('register:captchaDiv')).show()");
    } else {
        context.execute("jQuery(document.getElementById('register:captchaDiv')).hide()");
    }

    return event.getNewStep();  
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer. I would like to ask you, in method `onFlowProcess` **register** is id of `<p:wizard>`? And have you <p:captcha> inside <div> element? Thanks for answer.

Comment: No, `register` is just the id of a DIV element containing both, the `p:wizard` control and another DIV element with id `register:captchaDiv` that contains the `p:captcha` control. The important thing is to keep `p:captcha` outside of the `p:wizard` in the DOM tree while doing an absolute positioning by CSS to include the captcha inside the wizard at the GUI.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. I had a problem because I tried hide captcha by `visibility: hidden` but it is working with `display: none`. Thank you for help!